# How to properly require PHP files

Tags: php, require

I'm using 2 main PHP files for scripts on my website. One that focuses on accessing data from a MySQL database and one that contains functions required for the website. In some functions (in the functions file) I need to call functions from my MySQL file. I don't understand how to properly require the files so they are usable when they are necessary.

```
include 'scripts/MySQL.php';
include 'scripts/functions.php';
```

Is at the top of the page's file (I use functions from both files directly).
Then when I need to use MySQL functions in `functions.php`, the MySQL functions are null if I don't require `MySQL.php` at the top of the `functions.php` file, but if I do, I get this error: 
`Fatal error: Cannot redeclare getUserInfo() (previously declared in .../scripts/MySQL.php:2) in .../scripts/MySQL.php on line 16`. This is getUserInfo(line 2 is the first line posted, and line 16 is the last):

```
function getUserInfo($steamID) {
    $link = mysqli_connect(constant('DB_SERVER'), constant('DB_USER'), constant('DB_PASS'), constant('DB_NAME'));

    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM '.constant('membersTable').' WHERE steamID = '.$steamID;

    if($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
        return mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    }
}
```

How does `require` really work with inter-file dependencies? And why does my code act so weird/how do I fix it?

Also, if I want to access variables from another file, do I have to require that file in every function that uses the variables, or can I require it at the top of the file containing the functions (the latter does not seem to work)?

Sorry if this question reads a little confusing. I really could not figure out a good way to word my problem (especially cause I'm not sure I understand the problem myself).

Comment: Are you including the file from any of the other files too? It seems that you are including files more than once. Can you provide your complete code?

Comment: you included Mysql.php twice since functions.php needs access to it, but that's generating a fatal error.  The answer posted by FuzzyTree `require_once` should fix this

Comment: Just follow the PSR-0 and you'll be safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [`include_once`](https://www.php.net/include_once) or [`require_once`](https://www.php.net/require_once) to avoid redeclaring your functions

```
require_once 'scripts/MySQL.php';
require_once 'scripts/functions.php';
```

> The require_once statement is identical to require except PHP will
> check if the file has already been included, and if so, not include
> (require) it again.

Comment: But if I'm declaring it twice to get the fatal error, why are the MySQL functions null if I don't require it? That seems to contradict the assumption that it was already required.

Comment: Don't include or require files like that. You're going to be in pure hell. Use real classes and proper autoloading. That's why standards like PSR exist. To save you from the mess that programming in PHP can be.

Comment: If you have to resort to `require_once` to not load a file more than once, so that your code will play ball, then you have most likely lost control over what is happening in your code. You should step back and re-evaluate what is going on and then write the code properly.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen I ended up not having to use it, I corrected my code and it all works now.

Answer (score -2):

Don't do that. Take some time to read the following:

http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/

http://www.sitepoint.com/php-dependency-management-with-composer/

http://nelm.io/blog/2011/12/composer-part-1-what-why/

https://phpbestpractices.org/

http://www.phptherightway.com/

Make sure you follow ALL PSR's.

Comment: This is a common example, how a correct answer is being downvoted just for fun. +1 to fix an offset

Comment: Unfortunately, trolls gonna troll.